# Haskell: Converting Int to String

Tags: string, haskell, int, casting

I know you can convert a `String` to an number with `read`:

```
Prelude> read "3" :: Int
3
Prelude> read "3" :: Double 
3.0
```

But how do you grab the `String` representation of an `Int` value?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

The opposite of `read` is `show`.

```
Prelude> show 3
"3"

Prelude> read $ show 3 :: Int
3
```

Comment: @Lega: You may find this useful: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+String.

Comment: @ KennyTM A LOT of people will find that link useful! A link alone is +1, but for showing how to use it... That's +10 **Thanks :)**

Comment: Note that some organizations/standards strongly discourage the use of "show" because of its extreme polymorphism. A type-specific function (or, worst case, wrapper around show) would be helpful.

Comment: @JonWatte "Might", not "would". At the level of generality of this question, I don't think your suggestion is actionable.

Comment: Is there a way to do this manually without usyng system functions?

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy: Of course. You just need to do the same things those functions do. There's no real magic to this function, just a bunch of logic.

Comment: `readMaybe` or `readEither` are type safe and included in `base` under `Text.Read` ([Link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe)). Included for reference.

Answer (score 13):

Anyone who is just starting with Haskell and trying to print an Int, use:

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

someFunc :: IO ()
x = 123
someFunc = putStrLn (show x)
```

Comment: More idiomatic for Haskell is `putStrLn $ show x` (using right-associative operator $)

Comment: @Arlind: As someone trying to learn Haskell I *really* appreciate an answer like this.  I'm not trying to become a Haskell expert at this time.  I'm just trying to get simple functions to work and show the results to the console.  Later I can learn what is and isn't "idiomatic".  Thanks for helping out a beginner :-)

Answer (score 6):

An example based on Chuck's answer:

```
myIntToStr :: Int -> String
myIntToStr x
    | x < 3     = show x ++ " is less than three"
    | otherwise = "normal"
```

Note that without the `show` the third line will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use show:

```
show 3
```

What I want to add is that the type signature of show is the following:

```
show :: a -> String
```

And can turn lots of values into string not only type `Int`.

For example:

```
show [1,2,3]
```

Here is a reference:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Show.html#v:show