# How to convert IO Int to String in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I'm learning to use input and output in Haskell. I'm trying to generate a random number and output it to another file. The problem is that the random number seems to be returning an `IO Int`, something that I can't convert to a `String` using `show`.

Could someone give me a pointer here?

Comment: This does not help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784280/1268844

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's helpful if you show us the code you've written that isn't working.

Anyway, you are in a `do` block and have written something like this, yes?

```
main = do
    ...
    writeFile "some-file.txt" (show generateRandomNumberSomehow)
    ...
```

You should instead do something like this:

```
main = do
    ...
    randomNumber <- generateRandomNumberSomehow
    writeFile "some-file.txt" (show randomNumber)
    ...
```

The `<-` operator binds the result of the `IO Int` value on the right to the `Int`-valued variable on the left. (Yes, you can also use this to bind the result of an `IO String` value to a `String`-valued variable, etc.)

This syntax is only valid inside a `do` block. It's important to note that the `do` block will itself result in an IO value --- you can't launder away the IO-ness.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I've been spending a whole day trying to figure this out >_<!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

dave4420's answer is what you want here. It uses the fact that `IO` is a `Monad`; that's why you can use the `do` notation.

However, I think it's worth mentioning that the concept of "applying a function to a value that's not 'open', but inside some wrapper" is actually more general than `IO` and more general than monads. It's what we have the `Functor` class for.

For any functor `f` (this could, for instance, be `Maybe` or `[]` or `IO`), when you have some value
`wrapped :: f t` (for instance `wrapped :: Maybe Int`), you can use `fmap` to apply a function
`t -> t'` to it (like `show :: Int -> String`) and get a
`wrappedApplied :: f t'` (like `wrappedApplied :: Maybe String`).

In your example, it would be

```
genRandomNumAsString :: IO String
genRandomNumAsString = fmap show genRandomNumPlain
```

Comment: Just what I wanted to add, yes. +1. `fmap` is _really_ handy in `IO`.